# Android app paused while debugging due to SIGBUS signal

Tags: visual-studio, android-studio, debugging, android-agde

While debugging a native app using the Android Game Development Extension (AGDE) or the Android Studio, the debugger stops the app (as if it hit a breakpoint), and shows that the app received a SIGBUS signal.

I can press the Continue/Resume button, and the app resumes without any issues, but having so many SIGBUS interruptions is very annoying.

How can I suppress these interruptions?

Answer (score 2):

Workaround (for Android Studio Hedgehog and older, and AGDE 23.2.87 and older): Add the following to LLDB Post-Attach Commands:

```
process handle -p true -s false -n false SIGBUS
```

...and the debugger will no longer stop the process when `SIGBUS` signal is raised.

You can find LLDB Post-Attach Commands:

- (Android Studio) Under the Debug tab of your Run Configuration.
- (AGDE) Under the Debugging section of your project properties.

The above command has already been included in Android Studio Iguana RC 2 and newer, and will be included in AGDE 2024.1 and newer.